# Product certification for devices mounted on elevators

Tags: fcc, certification, ce

Do products that will be mounted on elevators needs extra certifications (apart from FCC or CE) to be sold in North America and Europe?

The product will be connected in the roof of the car, connected to mains (110V NA, 230V EU.)

EDIT: The product is an access control system that works with bluetooth (smartphone)

Comment: It might depend what the product is. Is it some sort of emergency braking system for the elevator, or light fixture, or fan to provide fresh air to passengers inside an elevator, or what? So what is the purpose of that device on an elevator?

Comment: It is an access control system. I updated the question.

Comment: There is, as far as I know, a separate lift directive. Quite likely this is a tougher one than the general Machinery directive. Wouldn't surprise me if it comes with mandatory type approval, though it might depend on if the product is safety-related or not. Either way this won't affect electronics requirements unless you need to implement functional safety and the like. "Functional safety lite" as per ISO 13849-1 in the Machinery Directive is often sufficient, unless this is an extra critical system, like control electronics for lifts carrying humans etc.